# How to find a usb drive letter trhough the Run box in windows and use it to run a script

Tags: windows, powershell

I am trying to run a script from the run box in windows. The problem is that this is on a usb and I want to be able to do this on different computers. The usb is called "bashbunny", but the drive letter will change depending on the computer. How do i find the drive letter and launch the script that is on the usb through the Run box?

Sorry if im not able to explain better :)

What I have done so far:

```
powershell ".((gwmi win32_volume -f 'label=''BashBunny''').Name+'payloads\switch1\r.cmd')"
```

Comment: I don't understand why you would open a command prompt and type in a command to find and launch a script on a USB drive with a known label. A double click in the GUI is much quicker I'd suspect.

Comment: @compo Actually I am going to set it up with the new bashbunny from hak5 so it is a lot faster to do it through the run box if possible :) and I dont want to open the command prompt, I want to do it through the run box (you know win+r) :)

Comment: @Compo They point is I want to plug in the usb and let it do all the work ;) And I was able to do it right now! :D

Comment: What is called `SCRIPTER` and what is called `BashBunny`? I am confused...

Comment: Haha I later changed the label back to bashbunny :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After tinkering a bit I found the solution:

```
powershell -executionpolicy Bypass ".((gwmi win32_volume -f 'label=''BashBunny''').Name+'payloads\switch1\r.ps1')"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a pure [cmd](/questions/tagged/cmd) solution (as you also tagged your question accordingly):

```cmd
(for /F "skip=1" %I in ('wmic Volume where ^(DriveType^=2 AND Label LIKE "BashBunny"^) get DriveLetter') do @for /F %J in ("%I") do @set "DRIVE=%J") && call "^%DRIVE^%\payloads\switch1\r.cmd"
```

Or, with an alternative `wmic` command line:

```cmd
(for /F "skip=1" %I in ('wmic LogicalDisk where ^(DriveType^=2 AND VolumeName^="BashBunny"^) get DeviceID') do @for /F %J in ("%I") do @set "DRIVE=%J") && call "^%DRIVE^%\payloads\switch1\r.cmd"
```